# Confused with the output of the following code

Tags: python-3.x

```
def double(n):
   global y
   y = 2 * n

y = 5
double(y)
print(y)
```

Confused with the output why is it 10 and not 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

The global keyword allows a user to modify a variable outside of the current scope, so when use global y, y change outside of the function. if remove a global keyword the output will be 5.